# countable intersection of closed convex bounded subsets reflexive banach space is non empty.

Tags: banach-spaces

If $X$ is a reflexive Banach space and $(C_n), n \in \mathbb{N}$ is a sequence of closed convex bounded sets with $C_{n+1}$ contained in $C_n$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$. How does one show that the countable intersection of $C_n$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$ is not the empty set?

Comment: How does one mark some answers as correct?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Do you know the Eberlein-Shmulyan theorem?

Comment: Would it be possible to please give me a few more details? I am not too aware of how to use it to prove the statement.

Comment: I need to prove that X being reflexive is weak sequentially compact(by the Eberlein Shmulyan theorem). But how does that follow from the statement given in the question?

Comment: Also, I have seen many versions of the theorem on the internet. Which one is applicable here?

Comment: If $x_n \in C_n$, Eberlein-Shmulyan says some subsequence has a weak limit point $x$.  Show that $x$ is in all the $C_n$.

Answer (score -1):

the proof can be seen in Introduction to Banach Space Theory by Robert E. Megginson.

Comment: Please try to describe as much here as possible in order to make the answer self-contained.